# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: java, android

I got Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

my mainActivity.java:

```
package si.mojkuzek.app.graphdemo2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
                new DataPoint(0, 1),
                new DataPoint(1, 5),
                new DataPoint(2, 3),
                new DataPoint(3, 2),
                new DataPoint(4, 6)
        });
    }
}
```

build.grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "si.mojkuzek.app.graphdemo2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}



dependencies {

    compile files ('libs/GraphView-4.2.1.jar')


}
```

How to fix this error?

I tried `multiDexEnabled true`

but it does not work

Also clean and rebuild